# Which type of variable should be initialized inside the class for different purpose

Tags: python

I have multiple variables which want to be initialized,

```
trading_symbol = "TSLA" # won't change in the future
trading_period = read_config_json("trading_period") # will changed only inside config.json
count = 0 # will be changed inside the class frequently
```

Where `trading_symbol`, `trading_period`, and `count` should be placed in the Trading class is the best practice in Python?

```
# define as a global variable
class Trading:
    # define as a class variable
    def __init__:
        # define as an instance variable
    def run():
        # running some trading logic here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # define as a global variable but won't be called by  importing
    trading = Trading()
    trading.run()
```

Comment: All of these sound like instance variables to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say instance variables are the best practice for this design.

```
class Trading:
    def __init__(self, symbol, period, count):
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.period = period
        self.count = count

    def run(self):
        ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    trading = Trading(symbol="TSLA", 
                      period=read_config_json("trading_period"),
                      count=0)
    trading.run()
```

Like this you will be able to get these variables in the `run` function to do whatever you want in the class itself.

Comment: I agree with this answer, but, in my opinion, it's silly to use singletons in python. I'm curious to know if you agree.

Comment: I would probably go with some kind of abstraction here. But if it is not a complex method then maybe a singleton should be good. It all depends on what you are trying to achieve and if it's too complex for one class to do it then you can split it up to whatever design pattern is most suited for the problem. I'd actually prefer in this situation to use a factory pattern here because at the end the run function should run the so called strategy of the trading class. But yes I would agree with you. It all boils down to what he's trying to achieve here.

Comment: what if how I get `period` is complicated(need few steps to get it), for the readability, is it ok to declare the period under `if __name__ == "__main__"`(but then it will become global variable which it should be, right?) or is there any others way to do it? @Roy

Comment: Period for example can be in a configuration file like json or yaml. And if it needs some calculation it should happen in a different file to encapsulate the class yes.

Comment: I'm also wondering why `symbol` should declare in the instance variable instead of class variable because it is not varied from object to object

Comment: Maybe it's the only symbol he wants to trade on. I don't know, probably a better option is to make a list of `symbols`.

Comment: what if assuming the symbol will not change forever, so should it be declared as a class variable instead of a instance variable? @Roy

Comment: It doesn't really matter that much tbh.

Comment: thank you, may I ask the last question, when I need to create an instance of another class in `Trading`, for example: `funding = Funding()`, should I create it under `def __init__(): self.funding = Funding()` ? @Roy

Comment: Or will you rather use Inheritance likes: `class Trading(Funding):`

Comment: I would put it in a config file.

Comment: Although it is a bit off topic, how to initialize a class in a config file may I ask? @Roy

Comment: how about `def __init__: self.period = read_config_json("trading_period")`, what do you think about doing this rather than passing `period` as a parameter? @Roy

Answer (score 0):

Is this class a singleton? If so, my preference in python would be to use global variables, use functions to manipulate them, and put the whole kit and caboodle into its own file. If you're quite set on using a singleton, then use instance variables wherever you can (but yuck). If it's not a singleton, it's usually quite clear what should be an instance variable and what should be a class variable: use instance variables when each instance may require its own copy of the variable (I.E the variable may have different values between instances), and use class variables for all else. To choose between class variables and globals, think about which classes will use the variable. If multiple, then maybe a global, unless it holds a mutable value, then it should probably be in the class that controls and changes it.

Comment: why if multiple classes will use the variable, it should be declared global? @JadeSpy